# Understanding a "state variable" RC-active filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, waveform

I have the following "state variable" RC-active filter:
[image]

If the input is a square wave, then when measuring the output I get a sine wave (channel 1 is the input and channel 2 the output):
[image]

And I don't understand why that happens. Could you try to explain it to me?

Edit:
The values are:
R1=11000;
R2=11000;
R3=7960;
R4=100;
C=10nF

Comment: Without knowing your component values, it's impossible to say exactly. You should also check the other two outputs. In general, it's fair to say that your gain is too large somewhere down the line.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks, I added the values. I've been Googling and I found something called the "Gibbs Effect", and I think that's what's happening here. Still trying to completely understand it, though

Comment: First, forget the Gibbs. That is not your problem. Second, replace your R4s with 10k - it is almost certain that your op amps cannnot drive this low a resistance. Third, identify your op amps and power supply voltages. Fourth, provide the input sine wave amplitude. Finally, disconnect your upper R3 and look at the outputs of all 3 op amps. They should all be sine waves. I suspect you have a bad connection to the - input of the first (leftmost) op amp.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly, but I'm not trying to fix the circuit, it's supposed to "convert" the sine wave into a square wave, but I don't understand how the circuit works.

Comment: Jack - is it really your task to use THIS circuit for converting a sinewave into a squarewave???

Comment: @LvW Actually, I think I'm wrong. The input was the square wave and the output is the sine wave, so it's converting a square wave into a sine wave. I did this last week and I forgot (been busy with finals). Still, I don't understand how it converts the wave. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK - this makes somewhat more sense. The first stage (bandpass) performs some filtering of the squarewave (attenuation of higher harmonics) and the second stage (Miller integrator) provides additional filtering. As a result you have sinusoidal signal - however, still with considerable harmonics (bad THD). But, in principle, it works.

Comment: @LvW Would it be safe to say that after the first op-amp the wave has the shape of a bell, after the second filter it has a triangular shape, and after the third op-amp it finally looks more like a sine wave?

Comment: Jack, no - I don`t think this would be the case. Don`t mix the transfer function of a bandpass (like a "bell") with waveform which comes out of the bandpass. More than that, the last stage does not alter the form - it just inverts (multiplication with "-1").

Answer (score -2):

Jack, Op Amp actually works like, let's say 'an amplifier' when we have feedback in the Negative input - just like you did. I don't know what is the frequency of your input signal, so, what it looks to is that your 10nF capacitor is acting as an 'open circuit' for the OpAmp in the middle.

Well, I mentioned the feedback in the negative input. In your case, however, the OpAmp in the middle looks like it's working without a feedback (because of the high impedance of the 10nF capacitor). OpAmp works like a differential amplifier, when there is no feedback. The differential amplifier will amplify the difference between the signals applied at the (+) and (-) entries. In your case, as the (+) is connected to the ground, the output from OpAmp1 will always be compared to 0.

I don't know if I made myself clear. To conclude, it looks like your circuit will behave like this for low frequencies. In case you start using a bit high frequency, you will certainly notice a different behavior - and not a square wave in the output.

Let me know in case you want some more explanation!

Comment: Karl, the shown circuit is a classical one - it is one of the well-known "universal (state-variable") filter circuits with a bandpass output and two lowpass ouitputs (Non-inverting, inverting). And the block in the middle is the classical Miller integrator circiuit (The purpose of the 10nF capacitor is to integrate; it does not act as an "open circuit").

Comment: The clue to what an op-amp is, lies in the three letters after the hyphen. It isn't "like" what you say it is and neither is your suspicion about the 10 nF valid. Like @LvW says, this is a well-proven standard circuit that doesn't need explaining. The problem lies in the implementation.

Comment: It looks like I was not that clear. I don't know how much technical is our guy here (@Jack) and this is why I wrote this way. Anyway, thanks for the explanation, LvW and Andy.